Instructions sub $0x8,%rsp , add $0x8,%rsp at the end of every single program
Every single program I've disassembled (except for libraries) contained this at the end
Disassembly of section .fini:

0000000000002f58 <.fini>:
    2f58:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    2f5c:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    2f60:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
    2f64:       c3                      ret

I don't understand the point of subtracting and then adding the same value to the same address of memory. What's the meaning of these instructions? I am new to low-level stuff.
I first thought that the processor saturates subtraction like the saturating_sub in rust, and the instructions mean "If 0x8 is smaller than %rsp, set it to %rsp" but it turns out it doesn't.

This is boilerplate code which makes more sense if there actually is something in the .fini section.  But as there isn't here, it seems nonsensical.

And the reason for this 8 adjustment is that conventions want the stack to be aligned on 16 bytes. call pushes 8 bytes for the return address, so it needs 8 more to be 16 aligned.

@fuz Then why does gcc and rustc add it to every application?

@TadoTheMiner Because the code comes from crti.o and crtn.o which are linked into your binary.  The linker lacks sophistication to get rid of these stubs for the case of no static destructors and it hasn't bothered anybody enough to add it in.
